# Arduino MIDIUSB button stops working when I light LED on push

Tags: button, arduino, midi, led

I have worked on a sketch for my Arduino Micro (not Pro Micro) that includes 4 mini arcade buttons with integrated LEDs. When I upload my sketch without the LED logic, everything works correctly but when I upload the sketch with the LED logic, the button press is recognized but not the note on/off message.

Does anyone see what would stop this from working?

Original Sketch

```
#include "MIDIUSB.h"
#include "PitchToNote.h"
#define NUM_BUTTONS  4

const uint16_t button1 = 2;
const uint16_t button2 = 3;
const uint16_t button3 = 4;
const uint16_t button4 = 5;

const uint16_t buttons[NUM_BUTTONS] = {button1, button2, button3, button4};
const byte notePitches[NUM_BUTTONS] = {pitchC2, pitchD2b, pitchD2, pitchE2b};

uint16_t notesTime[NUM_BUTTONS];
uint16_t pressedButtons = 0x00;
uint16_t previousButtons = 0x00;
uint16_t intensity;

void setup() {
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_BUTTONS; i++)
    pinMode(buttons[i], INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
  readButtons();
  playNotes();
}

void controlChange(byte channel, byte control, byte value) {
  midiEventPacket_t event = {0x0B, 0xB0 | channel, control, value};
  MidiUSB.sendMIDI(event);
}

void readButtons()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_BUTTONS; i++)
  {
    if (digitalRead(buttons[i]) == LOW)
    {
      bitWrite(pressedButtons, i, 1);
      delay(2);
    }
    else
      bitWrite(pressedButtons, i, 0);
  }
}

void playNotes()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_BUTTONS; i++)
  {
    if (bitRead(pressedButtons, i) != bitRead(previousButtons, i))
    {
      if (bitRead(pressedButtons, i))
      {
        bitWrite(previousButtons, i , 1);
        noteOn(0, notePitches[i], 100);
        MidiUSB.flush();
      }
      else
      {
        bitWrite(previousButtons, i , 0);
        noteOff(0, notePitches[i], 0);
        MidiUSB.flush();
      }
    }
  }
}

void noteOn(byte channel, byte pitch, byte velocity) {
  midiEventPacket_t noteOn = {0x09, 0x90 | channel, pitch, velocity};
  MidiUSB.sendMIDI(noteOn);
}

void noteOff(byte channel, byte pitch, byte velocity) {
  midiEventPacket_t noteOff = {0x08, 0x80 | channel, pitch, velocity};
  MidiUSB.sendMIDI(noteOff);
}
```

LED Logic

```
#include "MIDIUSB.h"
#include "PitchToNote.h"
#define NUM_BUTTONS  4

const uint16_t button1 = 2;
const uint16_t button2 = 3;
const uint16_t button3 = 4;
const uint16_t button4 = 5;

const uint16_t buttonLed1 = 6;
const uint16_t buttonLed2 = 7;
const uint16_t buttonLed3 = 8;
const uint16_t buttonLed4 = 9;

const uint16_t buttons[NUM_BUTTONS] = {button1, button2, button3, button4};
const uint16_t ButtonsLEDS[NUM_BUTTONS] = {buttonLed1, buttonLed2, buttonLed3, buttonLed4};
const byte notePitches[NUM_BUTTONS] = {pitchC2, pitchD2b, pitchD2, pitchE2b};
int lastpress = 0;
uint16_t notesTime[NUM_BUTTONS];
uint16_t pressedButtons = 0x00;
uint16_t previousButtons = 0x00;
uint16_t intensity;

void setup() {
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_BUTTONS; i++)
  {
    pinMode(buttons[i], INPUT_PULLUP);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_BUTTONS; i++)
  {
    pinMode(ButtonsLEDS[i], OUTPUT);
  }
}

void loop() {
  playNotes();
}

void controlChange(byte channel, byte control, byte value) {
  midiEventPacket_t event = {0x0B, 0xB0 | channel, control, value};
  MidiUSB.sendMIDI(event);
}

void readButtons()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_BUTTONS; i++)
  {
    if (digitalRead(buttons[i]) == LOW)
    {
      for (int x = 0; x < NUM_BUTTONS; x++)
      {
        if (lastpress != i) {
          digitalWrite(ButtonsLEDS[x], LOW);
        }
      }
      digitalWrite(ButtonsLEDS[i], !digitalRead(ButtonsLEDS[i]));
      lastpress = i;
      bitWrite(pressedButtons, i, 1);
      delay(2);
      while (digitalRead(buttons[i]) == LOW) {
      }
    }
    else
      bitWrite(pressedButtons, i, 0);
  }
}

void playNotes()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_BUTTONS; i++)
  {
    if (bitRead(pressedButtons, i) != bitRead(previousButtons, i))
    {
      if (bitRead(pressedButtons, i))
      {
        bitWrite(previousButtons, i , 1);
        noteOn(0, notePitches[i], 100);
        MidiUSB.flush();
      }
      else
      {
        bitWrite(previousButtons, i , 0);
        noteOff(0, notePitches[i], 0);
        MidiUSB.flush();
      }
    }
  }
}

void noteOn(byte channel, byte pitch, byte velocity) {
  midiEventPacket_t noteOn = {0x09, 0x90 | channel, pitch, velocity};
  MidiUSB.sendMIDI(noteOn);
}

void noteOff(byte channel, byte pitch, byte velocity) {
  midiEventPacket_t noteOff = {0x08, 0x80 | channel, pitch, velocity};
  MidiUSB.sendMIDI(noteOff);
}
```

Comment: What's the point of that `while` loop?

Comment: It was to maintain the LED until the next button press... I don't do this often.

Comment: It's blocking the whole program.